# Error QApplication: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt

I have installed C++SDK that have Qt but when I try compiling a code linking QApplication it gives me the error:

```
Error QApplication: no such file or directory
```

How do I link these libraries? I searched into the directories and there is a file named QApplication.h; So I tried to link it with -I (linking the directory) but it was still giving me that error.

Comment: The title of this question.The source is a simple file, I thought I didn't need to post this but simply: http://pastebin.com/972XtFUz

Comment: What is the output of `$locate QApplication`?

Comment: /home/ramy/Documents/C++QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtGui/QApplication
/home/ramy/Documents/C++QtSDK/Madde/sysroots/harmattan_sysroot_10.2011.34-1_slim/usr/include/qt4/QtGui/QApplication
/home/ramy/Documents/C++QtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/include/QtGui/QApplication
/usr/include/qt4/QtGui/QApplication

Comment: In the comments, i told you to write run `$qmake -project -d -Wall` & you included the `$` while executing the command. Exclude the `5`, that was just there to tell you that it's a command you have to write in shell

Comment: DEBUG 1: Project Parser: /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/include_source_dir.prf:1 :INCLUDEPATH: :*=: (.)

Comment: It aske me a command and writes what I have posted in the comment above, I just break with ctrl+c, no makefile is generated

Answer (score 84, accepted):

To start things off, the error `QApplication: no such file or directory` means your compiler was not able to find this header. It is not related to the linking process as you mentioned in the question.

The `-I` flag (uppercase **i**) is used to specify the include (headers) directory (which is what you need to do), while the `-L` flag is used to specify the libraries directory. The `-l` flag (lowercase L) is used to link your application with a specified library.

But you can **use Qt to your advantage**: Qt has a build system named **qmake** which makes things easier. For instance, when I want to compile *main.cpp* I create a **main.pro** file. For educational purposes, let's say this source code is a simple project that uses only `QApplication` and `QDeclarativeView`. An appropriate *.pro* file would be:

```
TEMPLATE += app
QT += gui declarative
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Then, execute the `qmake` inside that directory to create the Makefile that will be used to compile your application, and finally execute `make` to get the job done.

On my system this `make` outputs:

```
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/opt/qt_47x/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/opt/qt_47x/include/QtCore -I/opt/qt_47x/include/QtGui -I/opt/qt_47x/include/QtDeclarative -I/opt/qt_47x/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I. -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/qt_47x/lib -o main main.o -L/opt/qt_47x/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lQtDeclarative -L/opt/qt_47x/lib -lQtScript -lQtSvg -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lQtSql -lQtXmlPatterns -lQtNetwork -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread
```

Note: I installed Qt in another directory --> `/opt/qt_47x`

**Edit: Qt 5.x and later**

Add `QT += widgets` to the .pro file and solve this problem.

Comment: After Qt 5.x you need to add `QT += widgets` to the **.pro** file.

Comment: Still working in 2019, saved my bacon in QT5 running in Mojave. +1

Answer (score 138):

In Qt 5 you now have to add `widgets` to the `QT` qmake variable (in your `MyProject.pro` file).

```
 QT += widgets
```

Comment: here is how I have solved this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15120378/1141471)

Comment: Yes, if you are using qmake, the above line will add all the necessary compiler flags automatically.

Comment: @Timmmm well if I I'm new to QT Creator, I don't really understand where to add this line, what is qt qmake variable? some config project file or settings? (it could be anything, I don't know still)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16060355/7767664 there is more clear answer (add to .pro file)

Comment: Added widget to QT variable, I still get this error message.

Answer (score 39):

**For QT 5**

**Step1:**
`.pro` (in pro file, add these 2 lines)

```
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
```

**Step2:**
In `main.cpp` replace code:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
```

with:

```
#include <QApplication>
```

Comment: For Qt 5 it appears the include is *`#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>`*. That's according to *`find /usr -name QApplication`*.

Answer (score 16):

Looks like you don't have the development libraries installed. Install them using:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev
```

As you said int the comments that you have them installed, just re-install it. Now. to update the locate's database, issue this command `$sudo updatedb`

Then `$locate QApplication` to check that you now have the header file installed.

Now, goto the the folder where you have the code & type these commands

```
qmake -project
qmake
make
```

Then you can find the binary created.

Alternatively, you can use Qt Creator if you want the GUI.

- See the official documentation for more info. http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/gettingstartedqt.html
- To learn how to use Qt Creator, use http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.2/creator-qml-application.html

Comment: If I type qmake -project the shell freezes for few seconds, I have to break with ctrl+c.

Comment: Type `$qmake -project -d -Wall` in cmdline & tell where it hangs. Also, did you try QtCreator?

Comment: ramy@ubuntu:~/Documents/C++/Prova$ $qmake -project -d -Wall
    No command '-project' found, did you mean:
    Command 'project' from package 'turnin-ng' (universe)
    -project: command not found

Comment: Yes, I tried QTcreator, but also there it says there's no QApplication

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev` Install the packages & then try again.

Comment: nice, install libqt4-dev is just what I needed (I'm installing ruby gem capybara-webkit)

Answer (score 6):

In **Qt5** you should use `QtWidgets` instead of `QtGui`

```
#include <QtGui/QComboBox>     // incorrect in QT5
#include <QtWidgets/QComboBox>    // correct in QT5
```

Or

```
#include <QtGui/QStringListModel>    // incorrect in QT5
#include <QtCore/QStringListModel>    // correct in QT5
```

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure that the version of qmake you are using corresponds to the version of QT you want to use.

To be sure, you can just run :

```
$qmake -v
```

Your problem seems to be a symptom of a version conflict between QT 3 and 4, as can be seen here :

http://lists.trolltech.com/qt4-preview-feedback/2005-11/thread00013-0.html

To fix this, you can either delete your old install of QT, or specifically point to qmake-qt4 in your Makefile.

Comment: +1 for showing how to test the version, and for providing a link to further info.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add QT +=widgets in the .pro file before the first execution, if you execute before adding this line its not gonna working, so yo need to start file's creation from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Well, It's a bit late for this but I've just started learning Qt and maybe this could help somebody out there:

If you're using Qt Creator then when you've started creating the project you were asked to choose a kit to be used with your project, Let's say you chose `Desktop Qt <version-here> MinGW 64-bit`. For **Qt 5**, If you opened the Qt folder of your installation, you'll find a folder with the version of Qt installed as its name inside it, here you can find the kits you can choose from.

You can go to `/PATH/FOR/Qt/mingw<version>_64/include` and here you'll find all the includes you can use in your program, just search for `QApplication` and you'll find it inside the folder `QtWidgets`, So you can use `#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>` since the path starts from the `include` folder.

The same goes for other headers if you're stuck with any and for other kits.

Note: *"all the includes you can use"* doesn't mean these are the only ones you can use, If you include `iostream` for example then the compiler will include it from `/PATH/FOR/Qt/Tools/mingw<version>_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/iostream`

Answer (score 1):

> **Am using QT 6**

I found the problem to be on how i set the version

I had set a version greater than 6 meaning version 7 and above, yet am using QT version 6
so i changed from this

```
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 6) : QT += widgets
```

To

```
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 5) : QT += widgets
```

Answer (score 1):

> CONFIG += c++11

Write above code on myproject.pro

I'm using linuxmint 20.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have qmake in your path (which qmake), and that it works (qmake -v)
(IF you have to kill it with ctr-c then there is something wrong with your environment).

Then follow this: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/gettingstartedqt.html

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to update your SDK and start new project and recompile everything you have. It seems you have some inner program errors. Or you are missing package.

And ofc do what Abdijeek said.

Comment: I don't get it why are you having problem if you have installed package..what SDK and NDK are you using? and what tool you have for developing? QT creator? QT necessitas?

Answer (score -1):

You can change build versiyon.For example i tried QT 5.6.1 but it didn't work.Than i tried QT 5.7.0 .So it worked  , Good Luck! :)

Answer (score -1):

#include 
#include

#include "ui_mainwindow.h" **Error here**
...

I have fix:
I use KDevelop, File-­>Open..->build-­>build -­>(clic on ui_mainwindow.h) -­> Open

Voila!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).